# Avoiding data alignment in OpenCL

Tags: opencl

I need to pass a complex data type to OpenCL as a buffer and I want (if possible) to avoid the buffer alignment.

In OpenCL I need to use two structures to differentiate the data passed in the buffer casting to them:

```
typedef struct
{
   char a;
   float2 position;
} s1;

typedef struct
{
   char a;
   float2 position;
   char b;
} s2;
```

I define the kernel in this way:

```
__kernel void 
Foo(
   __global const void* bufferData,
   const int amountElements // in the buffer
)
{
   // Now I cast to one of the structs depending on an extra value
   __global s1* x = (__global s1*)bufferData;

}
```

And it works well only when I align the data passed in the buffer.

The question is: Is there a way to use **_*attribute*_ ((packed))** or **_*attribute*_((aligned(1)))** to avoid the alignment in data passed in the buffer?

Answer (score 1):

If padding the smaller structure is not an option, I suggest passing another parameter to let your kernel function know what the type is - maybe just the size of the elements.

Since you have data types that are 9 and 10 bytes, it may be worth a try padding them both out to 12 bytes depending on how many of them you read within your kernel.

Something else you may be interested in is the extension: cl_khr_byte_addressable_store
http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/cl_khr_byte_addressable_store.html

update:
I didn't realize you were passing a mixed array, I thought It was uniform in type. If you want to track the type on a per-element basis, you should pass a list of the types (or codes). Using float2 on its own in bufferData would probably be faster as well.

```
__kernel void 
Foo(
   __global const float2* bufferData,
   __global const char* bufferTypes,
   const int amountElements // in the buffer
)
```

Comment: Hi @mfa, are you sure that padding is not an option? Because What I really need to pass in the buffer is a tree with two different type of nodes so the work will be a little hard. I'm passing one byte in each node indicating what type of node it is.

Comment: What is it you are trying to do exactly? I made an update above with another suggestion.

Comment: I'm trying to send a Tree to the GPU memory but I'm trying to avoid the memory padding because i'll have to take a lot of care in the design of the buffer and the program in OpenCL but if padding is a must then I'll have to do it. 

I was thinking to create an algorithm to do the padding. I've to pass a **float3** so if I pass it as **float2** then the OpenCL's code become unclear so I prefer to do the padding and have a clear OpenCL's code.

Thank you for your help